# How can I change the text size in Pinta 1.3?

Tags: 14.04, pinta

I was using the text tool in `Pinta` image editor in Ubuntu 14.04. How do I change the text size in Pinta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the text tool, the text toolbar automatically appears and from there you can easily change the font size, including font-color, font-style, and several other things.